# nginx main page appears instead of my app

Tags: docker, express, nginx

I have a simple express app:

```
const express = require('express');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const app = express();

app.get('/', (_, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({
        type: 'test'
    })
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('App is running at 3000')
})
```

And I use nginx with the following configuration:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  app.dev www.app.dev;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_min_length 1100;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types
    text/plain
    text/css
    text/js
    text/xml
    text/javascript
    application/javascript
    application/x-javascript
    application/json
    application/xml
    application/rss+xml
    image/svg+xml;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_redirect off;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://app:3000;
    }
}
```

I have a docker-compose to run these two services together with some other:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
 
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch
    build:
      context: elasticsearch/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: volume
        source: elasticsearch
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: changeme
    links: 
      - kibana
    networks:
      - elk

  logstash:
    container_name: logstash
    build:
      context: logstash/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/config/logstash.yml
        target: /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/pipeline
        target: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
        read_only: true
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
      - "9600:9600"
    expose: 
      - "5044"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  kibana:
    container_name: kibana
    build:
      context: kibana/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./kibana/config/kibana.yml
        target: /usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
        read_only: true
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - elk

  app:
    container_name: app
    build : ./app
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules/ # make node_module empty in container
    command: npm start
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - elk

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/config:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./nginx/log:/var/log/nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    links:
      - app:app
    depends_on: 
      - app
    networks:
      - elk

  filebeat:
    container_name: filebeat
    build: ./filebeat
    entrypoint: "filebeat -e -strict.perms=false"
    volumes:
      - ./filebeat/config/filebeat.yml:/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml
      - ./nginx/log:/var/log/nginx
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on: 
      - app
      - nginx
      - logstash
      - elasticsearch
      - kibana
    links: 
      - logstash

networks:
  elk:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  elasticsearch:
```

The problem is that if I visit `localhost:80` I am seeing the nginx main page and not what I would expect namely the message `{"type":"test"}`. Any idea of what causes this error?

Comment: First, check the nginx conf is exist in "/etc/nginx/conf.d" or not. If its exist, do you set the host header to your request? try this one: curl -H "Host: app.dev" localhost

Comment: In the path "/etc/nginx/conf.d" exists my configuration file that I have mentioned above. If I do this command I am getting: `{"type":"test"}` in my terminal. I did not get what to include in my configuration file though.

Answer (score 0):

You set "server_name  app.dev www.app.dev;" in the nginx config, so only requests with host headers "app.dev" and "www.app.dev" match this configuration. If you don't set the host header, then they match with the default config in /etc/nginx.conf. Please set the host header to your request.

```
curl -H "Host: app.dev" localhost
```

Also, you can set "127.0.0.1 app.dev www.app.dev" in your host ("/etc/hosts" in linux) and open app.dev in browser or use curl in your terminal:

```
curl app.dev
```

however, you can remove the "server_name app.dev www.app.dev;" line from nginx config and test without the host header.